# Exclude sub package while defining dependency on AAR file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I am adding a dependency (AAR file - **core-project.aar**) in libs.

Structure of **classes.jar** in **core-project.aar** file

```
- classes.jar
    -com
        - android.example
            - DummyClass
            - UserClass
        - android.code
            - ABC...
```

I import this AAR as

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
.
.
dependencies {
    compile (name:'core-project', ext:'aar')
}
```

I do **not** want to **include** *com.android.example* **subpackage** from this AAR.
Please suggest how can I avoid the inclusion of a subpackage from AAR.

Comment: You should not remove classes from an aar file

Comment: @gabriel  That package is an independent package(external library) and attached in **classes.jar** of **AAR** while use **proguard**. so I want to remove that subpackage as that same jar is also added in **another AAR project** which I am using.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope. I think its not possible.

It should be kept in mind while creating library (AAR file) by developer. They should create new project for those subpackage which are independent and include as dependency. (Same as google play service, which have too many component as ads, location, auth etc.)